# Has_one relation with a specific foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Task model, I would like to create two has_one relation with the pricer model. To do that, I added the value **:client_pricer_id** and **:presta_pricer_id** to my Task table. And now, I want to create an has_one for each of them

My code :

Migration file :

```
class AddPricerToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :tasks, :client_pricer_id, :integer, foreign_key: true
    add_column :tasks, :presta_pricer_id, :integer, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Task model

```
  has_one :client_pricer, :class_name => 'Pricer', :foreign_key => 'client_pricer_id'
  has_one :presta_pricer, :class_name => 'Pricer', :foreign_key => 'presta_pricer_id'
```

View :

```
@task.client_pricer
```

Error :

> SQLException: no such column: pricers.presta_pricer_id

I certainly forgot to specify a variable in my has_one line. But I don't know which one :)

Comment: So do you have a migration for them and you run the migration?

Comment: Hi Ursus, yes I made the migration, but there are just referenced has integer, should I have to precise something else ?

Comment: please add the migration to your post

Comment: Ok, I've founded the error, thanks you @Ursus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `belongs_to` not `has_one`.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client_pricer, class_name: 'Pricer', inverse_of: :client_pricer_tasks
  belongs_to :presta_pricer, class_name: 'Pricer', inverse_of: :presta_pricer_tasks
end

class Pricer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_pricer_tasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: :client_pricer_id
  has_many :presta_pricer_tasks, class_name: 'Task', foreign_key: :presta_pricer_id
end
```

This is a really common mixup due to the confusing semantics.

`belongs_to` places the foreign key on *this* models table. `has_one` places it on the other end.

The inverse of `has_one`/`has_many` is always a `belongs_to`. Otherwise the relations just point at each other in a circle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @max, I just figured out !!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my error have to change the has_one to belongs_to (because the key is into my Task model )

My code :

Task model :

```
belongs_to :client_pricer, :class_name => 'Pricer', optional: true
belongs_to :presta_pricer, :class_name => 'Pricer', optional: true
```

Comment: You don't need the `foreign_key` option here. But you will need it on the other end.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will remove it so ! Less code is always better